# simplexml-load-file -- remote or local loading?

Tags: php, xml, apache

Simple question for Apache+PHP: if I use [simplexml-load-file](https://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) will it make an HTTP GET request or will it load the file from the filesystem in case I have:

- Option a: `simplexml_load_file('test.xml');`
- Option b: `simplexml_load_file('http://my.website.com/test.xml');`

Moreover in the second option, will PHP perform a DNS resolution of my.website.com or is there a bypass mechanism?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a general hint: PHP will never behave like a browser regarding URLs—no `http://` assumption, not `www.` adding, not Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A will load it straight from the disk, option B will perform an HTTP request, including a DNS lookup.  There is no bypass for the DNS lookup, other than modifying your hosts file or putting in an IP directly.